# Is it possible to create custom byte in .net

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a WCF in vb.net inside VS 2010.  I have a handful of properties that are currently bytes (0 - 255) and represent different test scores.  Is it possible for me to create my own type based on this that will only allow values between 0 and 110?  For example, if I have

```
Dim a as Byte
a = 256
```

I will get "Constant expression not representable in type 'Byte'." before the code is compiled.  I want to have something like this for my own type so the below code would give me "Constant expression not representable in type 'myByte'."

```
Dim a as myByte
a = 110
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use predefined (native) types, as Byte, and implement some features, like overloading operators to check minimum and maximum values. However, not every operator can be overloaded, what, in this case, includes the assignement operator '='.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx and the tutorials if it helps somewhat.

To assign a value tp your type you can make use of properties or methods that set the value checking for boudaries and other conditions, perfectly doable.

But to define it as a native... negative, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, I don't think that's possible. You'll have to use a constructor to initialize your myByte instance and do the range check at runtime (not sure how useful that would be).