# How should I implement a custom numeric data type in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net, types, numbers

Visual Basic .NET provides several numeric value types built-in (`Integer`, `Double`, etc.), each with their own ranges of valid values. In most cases, these are fine for what I am doing.

However, sometimes I find myself wanting a numeric value type with my own custom range of valid values, among other things. Suppose I frequently work with values representing a quantity which can only ever be between two values (say, -20 to 500, as a hypothetical example), and are always an integer quantity. These requirements are enforced by the type everywhere it is used. Let's call this type `SpecialInteger`.

I'd like to be able to do things like this with my custom type:

- Assign `Integer` values to my type:

  ```
  Dim someSpecialValue As SpecialInteger = 30
  ```
- If you try to assign it a value that's outside the range I mentioned above, throw an [OverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

  ```
  Dim notAllowedValue As SpecialInteger = 501 ' Invalid value.
  ```
- Throw something like an [InvalidCastException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx) if you try to assign a value that's within the range, but not a whole number:

  ```
  Dim alsoNotAllowedValue As SpecialInteger = 1.5 ' Also invalid.
  ```
- Have `SpecialInteger` recognized as something like a special case of `Integer` so I could continue to use it in assignment and arithmetic expressions like so:

  ```
  Dim someInt As Integer
  Dim myOtherValue As SpecialInteger = 234

  ' Neither of these statements should produce an error:
  someInt = myOtherValue
  someInt = myOtherValue + 5
  ```

...and so on. You get the idea.

However, I could not readily find anything online on how I should go about doing this. I'm guessing this will be implemented as some sort of `Structure` with a property which gets or sets the value, but I don't know what else is needed to fully and properly implement my type. Are there conventions to follow or interfaces required? Any advice, resources or how-to's would be appreciated.

Comment: Range Validation doesnt require a custom data type.  What you are describing just move the validation/range bracketing to some class

Comment: @Plutonix But then wouldn't I have to remember to call that class to validate my `Integer` variables every time I want to see if they could be valid values? I would tend to think it would be cleaner and less error-prone if I had my own type defined to do this checking automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: btw...this is a well structured and overall good question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your goals by defining various [Operator Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hddt295a.aspx) on your `SpecialInteger` type.

For the implicit type conversion between `SpecialInteger` and `Integer`, you need `Widening` operators.  For addition, you need a `+` operator.

Something like this will get you started.

```
Public Structure SpecialInteger
    Const min As Int32 = -25
    Const max As Int32 = 500
    Private backing As Int32

    Public Sub New(value As Int32)
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Property Value As Int32
        Get
            Return Me.backing
        End Get
        Set(value As Int32)
            If Validates(value) Then
                Me.backing = value
            Else
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(String.Format("min: {0}, max: {1}, Value: {2}", min, max, value))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function Validates(value As Int32) As Boolean
        Return (min <= value) AndAlso (value <= max)
    End Function

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As SpecialInteger) As Int32
        Return value.backing
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As Int32) As SpecialInteger
        Return New SpecialInteger(value)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator +(v1 As Int32, v2 As SpecialInteger) As SpecialInteger
        Return New SpecialInteger(v1 + v2.backing)
    End Operator
End Structure
```

Comment: Shouldn't Int32 to SpecialInteger be a narrowing conversion?

Comment: @Craig, strictly speaking, yes it should be a narrowing conversion.  However the OP requirement was to allow implicit conversion of Int32 to SpecialInteger and that requires a Widening operator to accomplish.  So for convenience in the IDE, I broke the rule and a run-time error can occur where it should not (Widening operations should always succeed at run-time).   10 lashes with a wet noodle for me. :)

Comment: Both this answer and [Alex B.'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43664809/3775798) were clear and of very good quality. It was tough to decide between the two for accepting, but I ultimately chose yours. Thanks to the both of you for your help!

Comment: Haha we came up with our answers almost at the same time and with very similar Concepts. Glad to see some convenience here.

Answer (score 1):

An own `struct` would be feasible.

I implemented something similar lately so I can give you some hints what could be helpful:

```
Public Structure SpecialInteger
    'private field to hold the integer value.
    Private _value As Integer

    'internal property with range check in the setter
    Friend Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set
            If value > 500 Then
                Throw New OverflowException("Value must be <= 500")
            End If
            _value = value 'value from setter
        End Set
    End Property

    'If you want to compare two SpecialIntegers
    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If Not (TypeOf obj Is SpecialInteger) Then
            Return False
        End If
        Dim s = CType(obj, SpecialInteger)
        Return s.Value = Me.Value
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Value.GetHashCode()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
       Return Value.ToString()
    End Function

    'If you want to comapre with =, <> >, < or do math ops +, -, 
    Public Shared Operator =(s1 As SpecialInteger, s2 As SpecialInteger) As Boolean
        Return s1.Equals(s2)
    End Operator

    'same for <>
    Public Shared Operator <>(s1 As SpecialInteger, s2 As SpecialInteger) As Boolean
     '...
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator <(s1 As SpecialInteger, s2 As SpecialInteger) As Boolean
        Return s1.Value < s2.Value
    End Operator

    'same for >
    Public Shared Operator >(s1 As SpecialInteger, s2 As SpecialInteger) As Boolean
           '...
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator +(s1 As SpecialInteger, s2 As SpecialInteger) As Integer
        Return s1.Value + s2.Value
    End Operator

    'same for -
    Public Shared Operator -(s1 As SpecialInteger, s2 As SpecialInteger) As Integer
      '...
    End Operator

    'Dim si as SpecialInteger = 5
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(s As SpecialInteger) As Integer
        Return s.Value
    End Operator

    'Dim i as Integer = si
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(s As Integer) As SpecialInteger
        Return New SpecialInteger() With  {Key .Value = s }
    End Operator
End Structure
```

Some Tests:

```
Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim someSpecialValue As SpecialInteger = 30
    Dim someInt As Integer = someSpecialValue

    Dim someSpecialValue2 As SpecialInteger = 10
    Dim sum As Integer = someSpecialValue2 + 4

    'The following line produces a runtime OverflowException:
    Dim someInvalid As SpecialInteger = 501

    'The following line produces a compile error:
    'SpecialInteger someInvalid2 = 1.5;

    Console.WriteLine(someSpecialValue.ToString()) '30
    Console.WriteLine(someInt.ToString()) '30
    Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString()) '14
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

P.S.: I wrote this in C# and used an online code converter to VB. Hope that everything is correct.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I liked your addition of testing code at the bottom. It gave me ideas for writing my own unit tests in Visual Studio for my new type. Thanks for the input!

Comment: A note about the `SpecialInteger someInvalid2 = 1.5;` line you have above: I noticed that if you try to assign a literal to a variable of a built-in numeric type which is outside that type's range, you'll get a red squiggle under it in VS and a "Constant expression not representable in type" tooltip. It would be nice if `SpecialInteger` also supported that, but it's [apparently not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5918639/3775798). Oh, well. Just something I'm leaving here in case anybody else is wondering.